# Good kit for repairing iPhones?

Tags: iphone

Can someone recommend a good kit for repairing iPhone 4s and 5s?

We have a whole fleet of iPhones here and they often need to be repaired.  If they are beyond EOL or we aren't getting a warrenty on them, I'd like to be able to get as much life out of them as I can.

Comment: kit or tool box, or test set up or all of the above

Comment: I only ever head of a kit...what are those other things?

Answer (score 2):

If you look on [ifixit.com](http://www.ifixit.com)  for their iPhone tear downs.

The not only show you how to do each iPhone but also list the tools they use.

[iPhone 4S](http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/iPhone+4S+Teardown/6610)

[iPhone 5](http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/iPhone+5+Teardown/10525)

[iPhone 4](http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/iPhone+4+Teardown/3130)

For example: iPhone 5

iPhone 5-Point Pentalobe P2 Screwdriver,
Tweezers,
Phillips #00 Screwdriver,
Small Suction Cup,
Spudger

Answer (score 1):

A side of standard screwdrivers, tweezers, (hammer and chisel) and so on, you can find on amazon to buy.

There are specialized tools for those who have more than one phone to fix.

Take look here for some ideas:
[Special repair tools](http://www.cultofmac.com/252956/genius-bar-repair-gifcity/).

As for parts and other tools:

You will need a lot of 
On/off switches (assemblies)

Followed by cracked screens.
Followed by dead batteries.

Isopropanol (alcohol)
Compressed air gun

Spare SIM chips (unlocked)